# To find all possible combinations and sum in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

**Input**: Input dataframe as mentioned below:

| Sno | No |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

**Output**: All possible combinations to find sum

| Sno | No |
| --- | --- |
| A,B | 3 |
| A,C | 4 |
| B,C | 5 |
| A,B,C | 6 |

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `combinations` from itertools:

```
from itertools import combinations
e = [[','.join(j),df.No[np.in1d(df.Sno, j)].sum()] for i in df.index + 1 for j in combinations(df.Sno,i)]

pd.DataFrame(e)
 
       0  1
0      A  1
1      B  2
2      C  3
3    A,B  3
4    A,C  4
5    B,C  5
6  A,B,C  6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.combinations` and compute sum of values another column like below:

```
from itertools import combinations

res = [] 
for i in range(2, df['Sno'].nunique()+1):
    for tpl in combinations(df['Sno'], i):
        res.append([tpl,df.loc[df['Sno'].isin(tpl), 'No'].sum()]

# One line:
# res = [[tpl,df.loc[df['Sno'].isin(tpl), 'No'].sum()] for i in range(2, df['Sno'].nunique()+1) for tpl in combinations(df['Sno'], i) ]
```

Output:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Combinations', 'Sum'])

    Combinations   Sum
0   (A, B)         3
1   (A, C)         4
2   (B, C)         5
3   (A, B, C)      6
```

Explanation:

```
>>> list(combinations(['A','B','C'], 2))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]

>>> df.loc[df['Sno'].isin(('A','B')), 'No']
0    1
1    2
Name: No, dtype: int64

>>> df.loc[df['Sno'].isin(('A','B')), 'No'].sum()
3
```